# maven download plugin to add downloaded resource to jar

Tags: java, maven

I am using download-maven-plugin to download some of resources to be used in my project. The download is successful and I can use the downloaded file.

However, what I want is to include the downloaded file in the JAR.

Note : The resource file will be included in the JAR when it was pre-downloaded before running the build, but if it is not present (e.g. deleted or I want to update it perhaps) the resource file is not included in the JAR.

Basically what I want is to include the recently downloaded file (from mvn clean install) in the output JAR.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-download-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>download-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wget</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>https://downloadurl</url>
                        <outputFileName>error.json</outputFileName>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.resources.dir}/commons</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Same thing happens when I use maven-ant-run plugin.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>download-files</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <get src="https://downloadurl"
                                 dest="${project.resources.dir}/commons/data.json"
                                 verbose="true"
                                 usetimestamp="true"/>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Why are you downloading resources like that? Why not putting them into `src/main/resources`?

Comment: This is a shared resource between platforms and I like to automate things whenever it is updated, I want to get the latest every time I build.

Comment: **without manually adding it** :)

Comment: What kind of resources between platforms? CAn you be more specific what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

I changed the phase to **process-resources**..

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>download-files</id>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <get src="https://downloadUrl"
                                 dest="${project.resources.dir}/commons/error.json"
                                 verbose="true"
                                 usetimestamp="true"/>
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just download it to `${basedir}/target/classes` before packaging phase. You don't need it to be in sources in order to include it to JAR.